# Ionic 2 ion-scroll zoom div

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/

So I looked at the documentation and I don't understand how to use to the ion-scroll zoom feature. It doesn't work for me.

**I want to have the div inside the `<ion-scroll>` to be `pinch zoom` so the `text contents` and `img` you see in the example below to be enlarged.**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-scroll
        zoom="true"
             scrollX="true"
             scrollY="true"
             maxZoom="15"
             style="height:100%;width:100%;">

<div>text contents here</div>
<div><img src /> </div>

    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure they do anything. It appears that they get set, but aren't used in any methods.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/scroll/scroll.ts